# How to save files (pdf/excel) in another server?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I have a web API hosted on server `101.111.111.111`. It accepts files in form data. My question is how to save this files in another server(Ex: `101.111.111.112`)?. I didn't find much examples for this in web.

I have this code to save in my local folder:

```
var file = Request.Form.Files[i];
                                var folderName = Path.Combine("D:\\Loans", fileInfo.LoanID, fileInfo.Alias );
                                var pathToSave = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), folderName);
                                if (!Directory.Exists(pathToSave))
                                {
                                    Directory.CreateDirectory(pathToSave);
                                }
                           var fileName = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(file.ContentDisposition).FileName.Trim('"');
                           var fullPath = Path.Combine(pathToSave, fileName);
                           var dbPath = Path.Combine(folderName, fileName);
                           using (var stream = new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Create))
                           {
                                file.CopyTo(stream);
                           }
```

Comment: Well, the other server has to somehow expose the possibility of storing the file. Through API, file share or some other mechanism.

Comment: I think you need  grant access to the network share to the user that the ASP.Net application is running as.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

One way is that create a share folder on server 101.111.111.112 and then map that shared folder with map network drive...(In Windows) on server 101.111.111.111 and then use that folder like local folder in your code.